# Writing to plists located at resource folder in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Any one please answer me, how to write into the plist file which is located in my resource folder. Please write an example code for me.

Comment: "Please write an example code for me." sounds a lot like "Please do my job for me." This is a site where you go to get questions answered, not people to do your work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't. The application bundle is not writable on iPhone OS devices.

Answer (score 1):

```
-(IBAction)textFieldCheck:(id) sender {
    myPrimaryinfo = [[NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:6]retain];
    NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Date",@"Time",@"Address",@"City",@"State",@"Zipcode",nil];
    [myPrimaryinfo addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                                                  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",txtDate.text], 
                                                                  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",txtTime.text], 
                                                                  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",txtAddress.text], 
                                                                  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",txtCity.text], 
                                                                  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",txtState.text], 
                                                                  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",txtZip.text],nil]forKeys:keys]];

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myPrimaryinfo.plist"];
    [myPrimaryinfo writeToFile:path atomically:NO];
    NSLog(@"PrimaryInfo array: %@", myPrimaryinfo); 
}
```